# Getting a form using php

Tags: php, forms

I am currently making a website where they can create their own pages and the areas where they put their information are in their own boxes. Each box is a row on my server. I want them to be able to have as many of these boxes as they want. So before I have changed the website the form looked like this

```
<form method="GET" action="createpage.php">
        <input type="text" name="titleOne">
        <input type="text" name="paraOne">

        <input type="text" name="titleTwo">
        <input type="text" name="paraTwo">
        <button type="submit" name="button">button</button>
</form>
```

It also has the ability to be an image but that doesn't make a difference to what I am hoping you will help me figure out. I now want to change the form to something like

```
<form method="POST" action="createpage.php">
        <input type="text" name="boxTitle">
        <input type="text" name="boxPara">

        <input type="text" name="boxTitle">
        <input type="text" name="boxPara">
        <button type="button"><button>
//the button above will be clicked to bring another set of inputs as seen in the two above using javascript
        <button type="submit" name="button">button</button>
</form>
```

is there any way I can grab the whole form in one array and then split it up every 2 sets of information.

I am hoping the result would come out as something like this

```
$form = $_POST['(form)'] 
//$form would then look like this
$form = boxTitle => (aTitle), boxPara => (paragraph), boxTitle => (nextTitle), boxPara (nextParahraph)
```

it would continue like that for each extra time they clicked the button. Is this possible or am I going to have to rethink my design.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your expected result is invalid. An array can't have duplicate keys. Keys are unique. What you can do is to name your inputs: `name="boxTitle[]"` and `name="boxPara[]"` (notice the `[]` in the end). PHP will then read those as arrays and you'll  get two arrays with the inputs: `$_POST['boxTitle']` will contain an array like `['value of first box', 'value of second box', ...]` and the same for `boxPara`.